# How Does One Indicate the Firefox Profile With RemoteWebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Looking at the Selenium 2.0 (alpha 7) source it appears to be possible to set the Ff profile of the RemoteWebDriver via the capabilities API. Yet it is not clear how one would do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

// OR
// FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(...));      

// Init your profile 

// OR
// If you created the profile by providing a path to it,
// the path should refer to the one on the host of the WD server

DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<....>:4444/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to each Selenium grid 2 node a specific firefox profile, just set the 
**webdriver.firefox.profile** property:

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=my-profile -role node -hub http://mydomain.com:4444/grid/register

- The value of the webdriver.firefox.profile has to be the firefox profile name, not the location or the folder name

http://automatictester.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/selenium-running-custom-firefox-profile/