# How to set the firefox profile at the node end in remote webdriver/grid configuration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

It is always suggested to set the firefox profile in  DesiredCapabilities and pass that through the wire ,where the hub is running . Like below

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

    FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile(new File("Local Path to firefox profile folder"));
    caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");      
WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(url,caps );
```

**But sending the huge 87-90 mb profile info to hub over http ,for each selenium test case slowing down the test case execution .**

I have tried configuring the grid node with `"Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=E:\\Firefox_Profile_Location":"",` property in json node config file like below.

```
{
"configuration":
{
.//Other Settings
.//Other Settings
.//Other Settings
"Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=E:\\Firefox_Profile_Location":"",
"maxSession":7,
"registerCycle":5000,
"register":true
},
"capabilities":
[

{"browserName":"firefox",
"seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver",
"maxInstances":5,
"platform":"VISTA"
}
]
}
```

But running with the above configuration is throwing below error .

> WebDriverException: Firefox profile 'E:\Firefox_Profile_Location'
>   named in system property 'webdriver.firefox.profile' not found

Advanced thanks for any help on how to configure the firefox profile from the node side .

Comment: Why are you using firefox profile folder and not setting profile setting through selenium code ? What is the requirement for firefox profile?

Comment: By setting through the code , it has to get transferred over the  http to the node end , and it takes time . I want to reduce the time by setting the firefox profile configuration at node end with conde configuration settings .

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to use firefox profile name and not the location.

```
"webdriver.firefox.profile":"default"
```

Have a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151026171942/http://automatictester.co.uk:80/2013/04/07/selenium-running-custom-firefox-profile) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575554/selenium-node-ignores-firefox-settings-and-sets-its-own-setting-profile-doesnt) and [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/14b69pd7q0/has-the-json-format-changed-for-grid-node-config-i-am-getting-an-error)

If you want know how to create a profile follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default) and [this](https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the profile in the `capabilities` object as a base64 encoded zip:

```json
var fs = require('fs');
```

```
capabilities: [
  {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    seleniumProtocol: 'WebDriver',
    maxInstances: 5,
    platform: 'VISTA',
    firefox_profile: new Buffer(fs.readFileSync("./profile.zip")).toString('base64')
  }
]
```

Moreover Firefox creates the missing files for a given profile. So you should keep just the necessary files in the profile depending on your needs:

```csv
Preferences:  user.js
Passwords:    key3.db
              logins.json
Cookies:      cookies.sqlite
Certificate:  cert8.sqlite
Extensions:   extensions/
```